# How much does GT zaskar carbon comp cost?

Tags: carbon, hardtail, india

So i checked the bicycle GT zaskar carbon comb and its prize was 22k rupees and in other websites it cost more. What is the real price and is there any GT zaskar carbon comp for 22k rupees

22k rupees = 266 usd

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Exchange. This exchange does not work like a traditional forum. Financial questions can be very subjective.

Comment: A bike is worth wat someone is willing to pay for it. And with such little information about year or even if new vs 2nd hand, no one here can really even guess at what it would be worth to them

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the specs of a [2021 GT Zasker Carbon Comp](https://www.vitalmtb.com/product/guide/Bikes,3/GT/Zaskar-Carbon-Comp,31596). Included in this page are links for online retailers that may have this bike for sale.

Here's a link to the [official GT website and the Zasker Carbon Comp](https://www.gtbicycles.com/jpn_jp/zaskar-carbon-comp).  No price is listed but under the "Support" link at the top of the page is a link to get in touch with dealers in your vicinity.

The price of the bike will depend on the model year and whether it's new or used. I'm basically finding new bike prices for a model year 2022 GT Zasker Carbon Comp 27.5 wheel size to be around $2300 USD.  That price (in equivalent currencies) may vary widely from country to country.